# C#: How to read an Input for 'separators'

Tags: c#

I want to read an input via `Console.ReadLine()`. It is supposed to be a list of comma separated numbers (e.g 1,3,4,5,6, etc.). This input is stored as a `string`. Then I want to test for every number if it is a prime number and even or odd. For example, if a user enters `12,13` how can I get the single numbers?

Comment: [`String.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the inputed string as that:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
var items = input.Split(',');
var numbers = new List<int>();
foreach ( string item in items )
  if ( int.TryParse(item, out var number) && number != 0 )
    numbers.Add(number);
```

So you will have a list of numbers that you can check as you want.

All non number entry is ignored as well as 0.

If you want only positive numbers:

- Whether check `number > 0` instead of `!= 0`.
- Whether replace `int` by `uint`.